# Refresh lightning:picklistPath

Tags: lightning, aura, developer-console

I'm using the standard lightning:picklistPath component. I'm using the onselect handler to persist the change to the picklist to the database.

```
<lightning:picklistPath recordId="{!object.id}" picklistFieldApiName="{!v.objectPicklistName}" variant="linear" onselect="{!c.handlePicklistSelect}" />
```

```
updateRecord : function(component, record){       
        var action = component.get("c.updateRecord");
        action.setParams({
            record: record
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

However, after persisting I can't find a way to refresh the component in order to show the new picklist value.

A force:refreshView does not seem to refresh the component.

There is also no method I can call on the component to refresh it.

Am I missing something? Or is there a way to refresh the component?

Comment: When you are firing `e.force:refreshView`? Can you please edit the question and add the JS controllder.

Comment: @SarojBera In the callback of the Apex Action that is updating the record. The code has been added.

Answer (score 0):

With the same code you have posted, I tried and it is working for me. `e.force:refreshView` is also working as expected. Please compare your code with below example and see if you can find the issue.

*HTML Markup*

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" controller="LeadStatusUpdate">
    <lightning:picklistPath aura:id="picklistPath" recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                            variant="linear"
                            picklistFieldApiName="Status"
                            onselect="{!c.handlePicklistSelect}">
    </lightning:picklistPath>
</aura:component>
```

*JS Controller*

```
({  
    handlePicklistSelect : function (component, event, helper) {
        var stepName = event.getParam("detail").value;
        var action = component.get("c.updateStage");
        action.setParams({leadStatus:stepName , recordId : component.get("v.recordId")});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                if (state === 'SUCCESS'){
                    toastEvent.setParams({
                        "title": "Success!",
                        "message": " Status is Update Succesfully !."
                    });
                }
                toastEvent.fire();
                $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

*Apex Class*

```
public class LeadStatusUpdate {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void updateStage(String leadStatus , String recordId){
        Lead l = [Select Id ,Status from Lead where Id=:recordId] ; 
        l.Status =leadStatus ; 
        update l ;  
    }
}
```